# Dialogflow Prebuilt agents language

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es, api-ai, agents

I'm working in a chatbot with **EN** and **ES** locales.
The default locale is **ES**.

I want to add *small talk* using prebuilt agents. But here is the problem: Once I import the agent, this agent only appear with **ES** locale. It means that when I export the intents to my chatbot, this intents only has **ES** responses.

I want to get both, **ES** and **EN** responses.

The question is, how can I import this prebuilt agents with both languages?

Comment: Are you sure this question is about Smalltalk programming language?  What programming language?  Do you have minimal working (not working in your case) example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: No, sorry i delete this tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have responses in several languages within one Dialogflow agent, however, you'll need to have duplicate intents (one intent in each language). There's a Dialogflow multi-locale sample available up on [Github](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-multi-locale-nodejs) for further reference on this. Also, you can check out the official [documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/agents/multilingual).